# Is it possible to get a Windows CMD Console Application on Mobile?

Tags: android, windows, cmd, console-application, porting

As the question states I'm curious if it's possible to get a windows command prompt application to run/be emulated on mobile, preferably android.

I am the developer of a game that has sold a reasonable number of copies on steam and I have been asked many times to try and get it ported to android, wether this is possible however is another question.

Is this possible somehow?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer NO.  Not CMD Anyway.

CMD is a virtualized Command Line Interface that runs on top of Windows, is closed sorce and does not have a port to Android.

If you don't truly need CMD, you might be able to get it to run in "DOSBOX" or "WINE".

If not, you would have to use your original source code to create a version which will compile and run on Android.

**Just curious, what game?**

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for the response, I'll have heard the game can be run on Wine but I'll look into removing windows functions and see where I can go from there, thanks for the response. (The game is Warsim: The Realm of Aslona) :)

Comment: @GameDevBoi There are WINE and DOSBox emulators for Android, depemding on thw licwnse ypu may be able to wrap ypur game inside it and distribute it together, pr write a launchee that will configure ypur game to run in it if thw uaers install it ans just provide a link to it.